# Deserialize properties with property name prefix .net

Tags: .net, deserialization

what are options to deserialize dunamically build object's multiple properties(with known name prefix -> "prop") into list of strings/or any other type obj?

dunamic json e.g.

```
@"{
        "prop1": "value1",
        "prop2": "value2",
           .......
        "propN": "valueN",
 }"

preferable result
 
[JsonPropStartsWith("prop")]
list<string>properties
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dotnet code looks ok, but you should look up what the correct attribute of JSON.NET or the new System.Text.Json package. The json should look like:

```
{
  prop: [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    ...
  ]
}
```

This is the proper array notation in json, that nicely deserialises to a `List<string>`.

If you can't change the json, check out deserialising to a `Dictionary<string, string>`